# QtCreator: Imported cmake project compiles, but source files are not visible

Tags: qt, cmake

I have opened a CMake project using QtCreator. The project builds successfully; however, I cannot see the source tree in the repository browser. My question is, how do I make the source tree visible in QtCreator after importing a CMake project?

Comment: Did you try to right click on your project and make "add existing directory ?"

Comment: I did - the option is disabled.

Comment: Switch in project tree tab from project view to filesystem view

Comment: The project tree tab is the tree that is not populated

Comment: Is this using the latest version, right?

Comment: correct, I'm using the latest

Comment: Not sure it would help but you can try to right-click on the project and choose "Run CMake" to run cmake again on it. It usually helps in situations when e.g. new headers/sources were added to CMakeLists.txt but Qt Creator doesn't display them in the source tree as it doesn't know yet they were added - it seems it gathers the information about headers/sources by during or after the runs of cmake.

Comment: Also, I have once seen an issue with sources of a project not displayed at all on Windows 10. I believe it was Qt Creator 4.1. In that case what helped is using older version of Qt Creator, 3.6 if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Qt won't show files in the projects tab if they aren't used as a source for some target. If you add your source files path to CMakeLists.txt `add_executable()`, they will show up correctly.